# Laravel's Eloquent ORM versus Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have 2 tables: `users` and `articles`. `users` table has a column named `is_suspended` which accepts `yes` or `no`, and the `articles` table has a column named `is_published` which accepts `0` or `1`. To fetch an article data from the database, `articles.is_published` must equals `1` and `users.is_suspended` must equals `no`. Now suppose that `users.is_suspended` equals `yes`, if I try to fetch data of an article using Query Builder like this:

```
// first code:

    $articles = Article::join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')
        ->select(['articles.*', 'users.user_name', 'users.user_email'])
        ->where('articles.article_id', '=', 9)
        ->where('articles.is_published', '=', 1)
        ->where('users.is_suspended', '=', 'no')
        ->get();
```

This will work perfectly and will return nothing (because `users.is_suspended` = `yes`). Now let's try to fetch the same article with Laravel Eloquent ORM like this:

```
// second code:

$articles = Article::with([
    'user' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['user_id', 'user_name', 'user_email'])
            ->where('users.is_suspended', '=', 'no');
    }])
    ->where('articles.article_id', '=', 9)
    ->where('articles.is_published', '=', 1)
    ->get();
```

In this case I will get the next result:

```
[
  {
    article_id: 9,
    user_id: 1,
    article_title: "Article title here",
    article_body: "Article body here",
    is_published: 1,
    created_at: "2015-01-17 02:26:24",
    updated_at: "2015-01-17 02:26:24",
    user: null
  }
]
```

It will fetch data of the article even if the user is suspended, which is wrong. So my question is how to fix the second code to act like the first code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `with` to make sure you lazy load relationships but any constraints you put on it only apply to the loaded relations. To limit the response to articles where the user is not suspended you would want to use the [**`whereHas`**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations) method.

```
$articles = Article::with(['user' => function($q){
        $q->select(['user_id', 'user_name', 'user_email', 'created_at']);
    }])
    ->whereHas('user', function($q) {
        $q->where('is_suspended', '=', 'no');
    })
    ->where('articles.article_id', '=', 9)
    ->where('articles.is_published', '=', 1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: That is great. But how can I select specific columns and where should I put : select(['user_id', 'user_name', 'user_email']). I have tried to put it like this: $q->select(['user_id', 'user_name', 'user_email', 'created_at'])->where('is_suspended', '=', 'no'); but it cause an error says: (Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 4 columns).

Comment: Added it in for you, you put it where you originally had it, in the `with` methods callback.

Comment: It causes an error says: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given.

Comment: My error, I didn't wrap the with argument in an array. Changed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need `whereHas` instead of `with` (or both, but no need for `with` in this case), like @DavidBarker said.

However I suggest more, consider readability of this code:

```
$article = Article::whereHas('user', function ($q) {
   $q->active();
})->published()->find(9);
```

It makes use of [scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes).

So here's what you can do to make your life easier:

1. Change `is_suspended` to `bool` because:

   ```
   $user->is_suspended; // no
   (bool) $user->is_suspended; // true
   ```
2. Define scopes `suspended` on `User` model and `published` on `Article`:

   ```
   // Article model - on User accordingly
   public function scopePublished($query)
   {
       $query->where('is_published', 1);
   }
   ```
3. When you want to fetch single model use `find($id)` or `where('col', $id)->first()` instead of `get`, because the latter will return a collection, even though there's jut one result.